# Is it possible to add a new optional property to a Swift Data Model without having to do a migration?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, swift-data

I already tried and it works without a problem (in Test Flight), but I want to know if its a good idea for future cases to do the same on a production environment and why.
I also use cloud kit to backup the data on iCloud automatically, I don't know if this could represent a problem.

```
//Original Models
@Model
class Toys {
    var items: [Item]
}

@Model
class Item {
    var creationDate: Date = Date()
    var name: String = ""
}
```

It was showed in a view after some user input

```
import SwiftUI
struct Some_View: View {
    @Query(sort: [.init(\Item.creationDate, order: .forward)], animation: .default) private var items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items){ item in
                Text("item.name")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the optional var

```
@Model
class Toys {
    var items: [Item]
    var tempName: String? //<---This one
}

@Model
class Item {
    var creationDate: Date = Date()
    var name: String = ""
}
```

-Now on the "new input" view that lets say for the sake of this example; it's only an input for the name.

-I try to read this tempName optional var. If it has something in it I read it and put it on the text field. (In the case the user was writing something and close the app and then return.)

-If its null I give a default "" so it does not matter if the old model does not have it.

-On change of the textfield I save the new input to the optional var, and if the user save the data I return the temp var to a nil state.

```
import SwiftUI
struct NewInput_View: View {
    @Bindable var toy: Toy
    @State var name: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $name)
                .onAppear(){
                    name = toy.tempName ?? ""
                }
                .onChange(of: name) {
                    toy.tempName = name
                }
            Button{
                let newItem = Item(name: name)
                toy.items.append(item)
                toy.tempName = nil
            }
        label:{
            Text("Save")
        }
        }
    }
}
```